# access violation run-time error for pointer assignment using Intel Fortran 2017

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

```
PROGRAM TEST

REAL(8),POINTER :: Table(:)
REAL(8) tbl_tmp(99)

ALLOCATE(Table(3))
tbl_tmp = 1.0
Table = tbl_tmp

......

WRITE(*,*) "Something here"

END PROGRAM TEST
```

I have an issue when i tried to compile/run an old code with the Intel Fortran 2017 compiler. The code above is an example. I have this sort of instances in an old fortran source. I know the code is written incorrectly but the whole program is huge so I don't want to  modify the source.

The example above compiles and run successfully in IVF2013 but i get a run-time error when using IVF2017.

```
ERROR: Unhandled exception at 0x77799AAA (ntdll.dll) in test1.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x777D58E8).
```

Is there any compiler option for IVF2017 which can mimic that of IVF2013 to be able to run the code above succefully using IVF2017?? I really have no idea what's wrong here and hoping someone can give me insights on this.

Comment: you can not assign an array with 99 elements to another with 3 elements!.

Comment: @M.Chinoune yes.. but as far as I know the fortran auto reallocation `realloc_lhs` can deal with that problem.

Comment: but you did allocate a pointer (not an allocatable array) which means it will act as a fixed-size array.